# How to change a Jbutton's function on clicking another Jbutton?

Tags: java

I am writing a program which will convert weight in pounds to kilograms and also weight in Kilograms to pounds. The output window is as follows:

[image]

When I want to convert Kilograms to Pounds I click switch button and the output changes as follows:

[image]

But the problem is when I click "Convert" it still converts weight to Kilogram instead of Pounds.

I want the "Convert" button's function to change when I click the "Switch" button so it will convert the weight in Kilograms to pounds. Please help.

My source code is as follows:

```
public class convertApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JLabel poundlbl = new JLabel("Weight in Pounds");
private JLabel kglbl = new JLabel("Weight in Kilograms");

private JTextField poundbx= new JTextField(12);
private JTextField kgbx= new JTextField(12);

private JButton conbtn=new JButton("Convert");
private JButton switchbtn=new JButton("Switch");
private JButton newconbtn=new JButton("Convert");
private JPanel bxPanel = new JPanel();

public convertApp(){
    super("Weight Converter");
    bxPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,29,5,5));
    bxPanel.add(poundlbl);
    bxPanel.add(poundbx);
    bxPanel.add(kglbl);
    bxPanel.add(kgbx);
    bxPanel.add(conbtn);
    bxPanel.add(switchbtn);

    //bxPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);



    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));
    this.add(bxPanel);



    this.setVisible(true);
    //what to do if i close
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //put window in the center
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //disable resize
    this.setResizable(false);
    //pack all the components within the window
    this.pack();

    conbtn.addActionListener(this);
    switchbtn.addActionListener(this);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evnt){
   if(evnt.getSource()==conbtn){
        String poundtext = poundbx.getText();
        int pound = Integer.parseInt(poundtext);

        double kilo = pound * 0.453592;

        kgbx.setText(""+kilo);
    }

   else if(evnt.getSource()==switchbtn)
    {
        poundlbl.setText("Weight in Kilograms:");
        kglbl.setText("Weight in Pounds:");

        if(evnt.getSource()==conbtn){
        String kilotext = poundbx.getText();
        int kilo = Integer.parseInt(kilotext);

        double pound = kilo * 2.20462;

        kgbx.setText(""+pound);
        }

    }


}

}
```

Comment: you may want to look into this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

Comment: Is this behavior a requirement? I think there's more than one better way to do this without swapping the labels around.

Comment: The event source can't be two different buttons simultaneously. When the "switch" button triggered, you need to set a flag based on the new state, so you can inspect it when the convert button is clicked. Alternatively, use two JRadioButtons, one for kilograms and one for pounds and check which one is checked when convert is clicked

Comment: Thanks all for the help...My program is working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create boolean  Variable

```
boolean switch=true;

void kiloGramToPound{
//Convert Codes Here
}

void PoundToKiloGram{
//Convert Codes Here
}
```

Convert Button actionPerformed

```
if(switch==true){
     kiloGramToPound();
}else{
     PoundToKiloGram();
}
```

Switch Button actionPerformed

```
if(switch==true){
    switch=false;
}else{
  switch=true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...I have just one question..Where do I initialize the Boolean variable?

Comment: Class Variable                                           Public Class myclass(){ boolean Switch=true; myclass(){my Other Code }  }

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the function itself. You can create a flag that sets true or false (your choice) when you click the 'switch' button. Then check the value of that flag when you click 'convert' and perform the appropriate conversion according to your flag convention.

i.e.

```java
Boolean isPtoK = true;

// [...]

if(isPtoK){
  // convert pounds to kilos
} else{
  // kilos to pounds
}
```

I would create a separate function that switches the value of your flag when 'switch' is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not answering your question, but may I suggest you to try KeyListener/KeyAdapter instead of the combination of ActionListeners and buttons.

Example:

```
textField1.addKeyListener(new ConverterListener(textField2, "2.20462"));
textField2.addKeyListener(new ConverterListener(textField1, "0.453592"));


class ConverterListener extends KeyAdapter {

    JTextField destination;
    String multiplier;

    public ConverterListener(JTextField destination, String multiplier) {
        this.destination = destination;
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        JTextField source = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        String result = convert(source.getText(), multiplier);
        destination.setText(result);
    }

    private String convert(String value, String multiplier) {
        String result = "0";

        try {
            double dblValue = value.isEmpty() ? 0d : Double.parseDouble(value);
            double dblMultiplier = value.isEmpty() ? 0d : Double.parseDouble(multiplier);

            result = Double.toString(dblValue * dblMultiplier);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm very new to Java so I have no idea how a  Key Listener or Key adapter works..I really appreciate the help